# ko.JS databinding to fetch input from Text Area - Not capturing /n

Tags: html, knockout.js, data-binding, textarea, newline

Below is my code for the text area.

```
<div>

<textarea data-bind="value: environment" rows="10" cols="20" class="form-group"></textarea>

</div>
```

[image: Text Area]

I want to display the content entered in this text area in another DIV.

Below is the code to display the content of text area.

```
<div data-bind="text: environment"/>
```

This div is displayed as shown in the below image.

[image]

**Issue:**
The new line is not captured when I am displaying the content in another div.

**What all I tried?**
I tried below ways to see if new line /n will be displayed as is, from text area. 
But, no luck !

```
<div data-bind="html: environment"/>
<div data-bind="value: environment"/>
```

Please suggest if anyone has faced such issues.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the css rule `white-space: pre-wrap` to your div:

```js
var viewModel = {
  environment: ko.observable("initial text")
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Change text and click outside textarea in order to update value.</div>

<textarea data-bind="value: environment" rows="10" cols="20" class="form-group"></textarea>

<div>Entered text:</div>
<div data-bind="html: environment()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dirty, but... You can replace '\n' with '' for display div:

```js
var viewModel = {
  environment: ko.observable("initial text")
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>Change text and click outside textarea in order to update value.</div>

<textarea data-bind="value: environment" rows="10" cols="20" class="form-group"></textarea>

<div>Entered text:</div>
<div data-bind="html: environment().replace('\n', '</br>')"></div>
```